# wrapping text in css div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys for some reason my text is not wrapping in `Div`, I have three divs placed `inline-block` and `floating left`. If i don't use floating left the the divs gets pushed down.

***CSS code***

```
#OuterSection
{
border-top: 10px solid #0272b0;
border-left: 5px solid #0272b0;
border-bottom: 5px solid #0272b0;
border-right: 5px solid #0272b0;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #0272b0;
width:250px;
height: auto;
display:inline-block;
}

#InnerSection
{
width:auto;
height:auto;
text-align:center;
background-color: #FFF;
border-radius: 5px;   
text-align:left;
word-wrap: break-word;
float:left;
}

#SectionTitle
{
color: #FFF;
display: inline-block;
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: 5px;

}
```

***HTML code here***

```
<div id="OuterSection">
<span id="SectionTitle">section1</span>
<div id="InnerSection">

 testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest

</div>
</div>

<div id="OuterSection">
<span id="SectionTitle">section2</span>
<div id="InnerSection">

</div>
</div>

<div id="OuterSection">
<span id="SectionTitle">section3</span>
<div id="InnerSection"></div></div>
```

Comment: yes, that's correct,is it possible?

Comment: how would you use JavaScript to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`#Section{display:inline-block;}`

Comment: What section do you want me to put that in?

Comment: @Ozerich he did an HTML copy&paste mistake at first it's fixed now, there's no id Section in the HTML.

Comment: @micha Yes, you are right. But when topic started author's code was with id="Section". He had fixed it

Comment: @Ozerich yes that's correct but now the answer is not constructive anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Fix can be found here: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WGtQB/)

Used `word-wrap:break-word;` on your innerSection with `width:100%;`